# Where do I find VLC's source code?

Tags: vlc, source-code, open-source, source-packages

I have installed VLC 2.0.8 TwoFlower and I was wondering where I can find VLC's source code.

I am using ubuntu 13.10 and I don't plan to do anything with the code, I just want to have a look at it.